# How do I show menu list below hamburger icon?

Tags: html, css

How do I show menu list below hamburger icon?

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xkp0p7vc/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your HTML is not valid because li should be directly children to ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `display: block; clear: both;` to `ul.topnav.responsive li` and remove `float: right;` from `.topnav-right`.

```
ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: block; /*change with inline*/
    clear: both;
}

.topnav-right {
    /* float: right; */
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xkp0p7vc/1/)

Comment: Thanks Ismail, but how can I accomplish this if I want to have the topnav float right?

Comment: simply add  .topnav-right {    float: none;} in media query